# Vue + Tailwind : themeable profile page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, themes, tailwind-css

I want to create an app (something like a social network) that lets a user sign-up and enter a bunch of profile information. After this the user is allowed to select one theme (from a set of predefined themes) for displaying this information to other users that come to see the profile.

This is very similar to what Shopify's storefront themes are.

How should I go about trying to design a solution for this?

Apologies in advance for a very high-level vague question.

I know how to set the theme and/or colors etc at the time I writing my code (or maybe during the build step), but I am stuck at even trying to reason how to do this inside a product.

Comment: No apologies are necessary, but the question is too broad and so is not suited for SO, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . You can start by checking similar example projects on github to get some ideas where to start. It's unclear what kind of answer is expected in this case. In case this helps, in order to set a theme at runtime you should either have multiple prebuilt .css for different themes (can have a different root selectors in order to not interfere with each other), or use CSS vars in JS for all dynamically set colors

Comment: Thank you! I think this is exactly the answer / direction I was looking for. After I saw your comment I did check out both the options and I think I should be able to achieve 90% of what I need with multiple .css and just generate the index.html page as per user settings. Really really appreciate the response @EstusFlask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [tw-colors](https://github.com/L-Blondy/tw-colors) in order to create the predefined themes

```js
   const { createThemes } = require('tw-colors');

   module.exports = {
      content: ['./src/**/*.{astro,html,js,jsx,md,mdx,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}'],
      plugins: [
         createThemes({
            banana: { 
               'primary': 'steelblue',
               'secondary': 'darkblue',
               'brand': '#F3F3F3',
            },
            halloween: { 
               'primary': 'turquoise',
               'secondary': 'tomato',
               'brand': '#4A4A4A',
            },
            darkula: { 
               'primary': '#2A9D8F',
               'secondary': '#E9C46A',
               'brand': '#264653',
            },
         })
      ],
   };
```

Then apply the theme on the card container

```html
<div class='theme-darkcula'>
    <h2 class='text-primary'>Username</h2>
    <p class='text-secondary'>...</p>
</div>

<div class='theme-halloween'>
    <h2 class='text-primary'>Username</h2>
    <p class='text-secondary'>...</p>
</div>
```

If the theme classNames come from API response you should safelist them, otherwise tailwind will not generate them, see [tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) for more details

Comment: @l-blondy Thank you! I did find tw-colors and that is what I'll end up using most likely. Very useful tool you've made - thank you for that.